# Dart WebUI build error

Tags: html, dart, dart-webui

I am having problems adding web_ui to my existing dart application.
I haven't even added any of the webui specific code to my html file, i'm just trying to build.

I added the web_ui to pubspec.yaml and ran pub install.

When i run my build.dart file, it generates:

```
Uncaught Error: type 'AttributeName' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'name'.
```

This is what my build.dart file looks like (it is in root dir of my project):

```dart
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['bin/mywebpage.html']);
}
```

Also worth noting, i tried their auto generated webUI example and it works, i just cant add it to my existing project.

EDIT:

1. Yes, usually it is index.html, but it makes no difference. I did try changing it. 
   i am running the latest version of Dart M4.
2. When i run mywebpage.html in Dartium i get no errors, but {{dataValue}} is not replaced with its coresponding  data.
3. Dart Editor version 0.4.7_r21658
   Dart SDK version 0.4.7.5_r21658

This is all the info I am getting, the funny thing is clipPath is not unexpected, it is closing a opened clipPath tag :

```
warning bin/mywebsite.html:86:3: Unexpected end tag (clippath). Ignored.
        </clipPath>
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
warning bin/mywebsite.html:99:3: Unexpected end tag (clippath). Ignored.
        </clipPath>
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
Uncaught Error: type 'AttributeName' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'name'.
Stack Trace:
#0      _Analyzer.visitAttribute (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:403:48)
#1      _Analyzer.visitElementInfo.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:157:53)
#2      LinkedHashMap.forEach (dart:collection-patch:241:13)
#3      _Analyzer.visitElementInfo (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:157:28)
#4      _Analyzer.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:123:21)
#5      TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:15:50)
#6      TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:27:49)
#7      TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:35:48)
#8      TreeVisitor.visitElement (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:44:50)
#9      _Analyzer.visitElementInfo (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:175:23)
#10     _Analyzer.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:123:21)
#11     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:15:50)
#12     TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:27:49)
#13     TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:35:48)
#14     TreeVisitor.visitElement (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:44:50)
#15     _Analyzer.visitElementInfo (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:175:23)
#16     _Analyzer.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:123:21)
#17     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:15:50)
#18     TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:27:49)
#19     TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:35:48)
#20     TreeVisitor.visitElement (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:44:50)
#21     _Analyzer.visitElementInfo (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:175:23)
#22     _Analyzer.visitElement (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:123:21)
#23     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:15:50)
#24     TreeVisitor.visitChildren (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:27:49)
#25     TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:35:48)
#26     TreeVisitor.visitDocument (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:37:52)
#27     TreeVisitor.visit (package:html5lib/dom_parsing.dart:19:52)
#28     analyzeFile (package:web_ui/src/analyzer.dart:63:17)
#29     Compiler._analyze.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:512:24)
#30     time (package:web_ui/src/utils.dart:46:24)
#31     Compiler._time (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:714:16)
#32     Compiler._analyze (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:511:14)
#33     Compiler.run.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart:110:15)
#34     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:397:24)
#35     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#36     _CompleterImpl.complete (dart:async:129:21)
#37     FutureGroup.add.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/utils.dart:141:28)
#38     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:397:24)
#39     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#40     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:371:16)
#41     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:403:21)
#42     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#43     _CatchErrorFuture._sendValue (dart:async:415:14)
#44     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#45     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:371:16)
#46     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:403:21)
#47     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#48     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:371:16)
#49     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:403:21)
#50     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#51     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:157:21)
#52     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#53     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:157:21)
#54     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#55     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:371:16)
#56     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:403:21)
#57     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#58     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:157:21)
#59     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#60     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:371:16)
#61     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:403:21)
#62     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:294:26)
#63     _CompleterImpl.complete (dart:async:129:21)
#64     _SendPortImpl.call.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch:106:27)
#65     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)


Unhandled exception:
_FutureImpl._scheduleUnhandledError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:325:9)
#1      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:2240:21)
#2      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:2248:13)
#3      Timer.Timer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch:15:15)
#4      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6721:28)
#5      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6729:7)
#6      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:6737:23)
#7      _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)
```

Comment: are you sure about `bin/mywebpage.html` ??? Usually it's `web/index.html`  <- in `web/` folder

Comment: Could you right click on mywebpage.html and 'Run in Dartium' ? Is there any errors in tabs at the bottom ?

Comment: Could you post your Dart SDK and Dart Editor version ? You could find it in Dart Editor click on menu `Help > About Dart Editor`

Comment: Here is WebUI simple tutorial: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/web-ui/  could read post what you did differently ? (Again: please note all paths point to `web/` folder not `bin/`)

Comment: Also: There's an updated version of DartEditor: 0.4.7_r21658

Comment: I added web_ui to my pubspec.yaml, ran a pub install. I put a build.dart file in the root of my project and i tried to run it. Nothing else. Also i renamed bin to web, makes no difference

Comment: also i updated to the latest, no difference

Comment: could you post the content of `mywebpage.html`? and the corresponding dart code? I don't think the build file itself is the problem.

Comment: Link to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105935/dart-confusing-type-error/16312952

Comment: AttributeName is defined inside html5lib. Were you already using this library before add webui to your project? Could it be caused by web-ui running against an out of date html5lib?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is caused by the web-ui library failing a type check. It's expecting a String but getting an [AttributeName](https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib/blob/master/lib/dom.dart) class back from html5lib.

See this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/484). Are you using an xmlns attribute in your html - svg perhaps?

You could also post on the [web-ui mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/web-ui), or [file a bug report](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues).