# Dart confusing TYPE error

Tags: html, dart, dart-webui

I am building a web application using dart with web_ui.

Everything was working fine until i added the web_ui pub, and now, when I am trying to run a build.dart file I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: type 'AttributeName' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'name'.
```

What does this mean?

From what I understand, this means there is somewhere an instance named 'name' of class 'AttributeName' that is extending 'String' class.

I searched my entire project and there is nowhere a class named 'AttributeName', nowhere an instance of 'name'.

I have the latest Dart editor and SDK:

```
Dart Editor version 0.4.7_r21658
Dart SDK version 0.4.7.5_r21658
```

EDIT:
this is my build.dart file:

```
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/menyplattan.html']);
}
```

Also, i updated all the pubs

Comment: Can you post the contents of your build.dart file? And also the file that is being built?

Comment: If you started your project before updating to the latest Dart Editor, have you run Tools -> Pub Update while in your project?

Comment: i updated my original question with data you asked for

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080115/dart-webui-build-error ??

Answer (score 1):

This message looks like web_ui is failing a type check.

The similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080115/dart-webui-build-error) MarioP links to has a stacktrace showing this message coming from within the web ui library itself.

Do you have an xmlns attribute in your html?
Have a look at this [web-ui issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/484).

[AttributeName](https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib/blob/master/lib/dom.dart) is defined within the html5lib library. Perhaps web-ui is expecting a newer version of this library but getting an older one. Make sure you've done a pub install. You can also try deleting your packages folder and doing a fresh pub install.

This could be caused by out-of-date packages, but it could also be a bug in web-ui. See if you can get a stacktrace and [file a bug report](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues), or post it on the [web-ui mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/web-ui).